# Can't read my dataset located in home jupyter notebook on remote server with opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, loading, remote-server

Previously when I tried to install opencv with pip install opencv I got this following error

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

So I tried this command instead "pip install opencv-python-headless

I don't know if this is the reason why I couldn't read my dataset with opencv

Here is my code

```
path='/home/pfadim/env/ImageCLEFmed2009_.02/ImageCLEFmed2009_.02/*.png'
train=[]
for image in path:
img=cv2.imread(image)
train.append(img)
```

Here is the error that I get

[ WARN:0@114.826] global /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp (239) findDecoder imread_('h'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity

[ WARN:0@114.829] global /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp (239) findDecoder imread_('o'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity

[ WARN:0@114.833] global /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp (239) findDecoder imread_('m'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity

Comment: please add your error **as text**

Comment: `for image in path` is just looping over a string so it's going to return each individual character in that string, not file paths.  You need to use `glob.glob()` or similar